# javascript linking onclick to a .js to a file

Tags: javascript, buttonclick

I know how to connect onclick to a function(), for example:

```
<input type="BUTTON" value="Exit" onclick= "javascript: function();" >
```

However, does anyone know how to link onclick to a .js file?

Thanks a lot.